How to remove this lightbulb?
The lightbulb in this lamp fixture is defunct. How can I replace it? Is there a special tool needed?


@Traveler, answers go down there. Also, "pry".

There are two types of lamps.
One is twist lock, the other has simple straight pins.
Do not know which style you have but try...
With your fingers push it up and twist to the left.
For the pin type, just pull out.
